# How to insert meta data in wordpress API?

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type and trying to insert post with API, post saved correctly, but meta data not saved.

**API**: `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/custom_post`

Below is the Object that i pass in API

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "meta": {
        "next_qus": "test",
        "type": "text"
    }
}
```

**Response**

[image]
Any solution appreciated!